# Java 8 Streams API and Stack Class

Tags: java, collections, stream, stack

I want to understand behavior of Stack class when used with Java 8  streams API.

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();

s.push(1);
s.push(2);
s.push(3);
s.push(4);

s.stream().forEach( x-> System.out.print(x + " "));
```

As per the contract of Stack class, this code should print `4 3 2 1`.

But instead, it prints `1 2 3 4`.

Basically I want to Understand:

1. Underlying low level implementation details that is causing this behavior.
2. Any other known pitfalls like this when using Stream API to Iterate Ordered collections.
3. If I wanted to implement my own Stack class, which plays wells with Java 8 Streams, what changes are needed ?

Comment: *As per the contract of Stack class, this code should print 4 3 2 1.* ... only if you `pop` the contents unless the stack is empty.

Comment: a) What part of "the contract of the Stack class" makes you think that it should print `4 3 2 1` ? Please quote from the documentation. b) The documentation clearly states "the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class." - why are you using an obsolete class?

Comment: 1) `Stack` uses `Vector`'s iterator which is cursor-based with the starting position set to `0`. Their `Iterator#next` basically returns `elementData[cursor++]`, where `elementData` is a plain `Object[]` array used by both classes to store elements.

Comment: 2) Not really. The API is clear and well-documented. (These classes are obsolete, no one wants to use/support/improve them [partly because you couldn't change much without breaking something])

Comment: 3) Probably you need to override the behaviour of `stream()`, `spliterator()` (for Stream API), and `forEach()`, `iterator()` (for Iterator API)

Comment: Thanks Andrew Tobilko...exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Accepted answer. Thanks for reminder.

Comment: You are very welcome. But just dont tell anyone. I am told reminding people is A) not necessary and B) sooooo wrong ;-) ... and I very much appreciate the quick comeback. And note: when you want to directly "respond" to someone here: use @ username to have that user notified about the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Misconception: the `stream()` method comes out of the Collection interface.

And its javadoc tells us:

> Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source.

In other words: the "Stream contract" doesn't know or care about the "Stack contract".

Beyond that, that "Stack contract" is about "Stack operations". In other words: there is no guarantee about ordering of elements when *iterating* a Stack via streams.

And, javadoc from Stack itself tells us:

> The Stack class represents a last-in-first-out (LIFO) stack of objects. It extends class Vector with five operations that allow a vector to be treated as a stack.

So, you got it right there: A Stack is nothing but a vector (list), that provides **additional** operations that enable "Stack behavior". You can see that here:

```
for (Integer i : s) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }
```

So, even when "just" iterating your stack, leaving out the streamish part, it will print the elements in insertion order 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 5):

The `Stack` class is old (and actually predates the Collections API), you should be using `Deque`. As the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) javadoc notes *Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class*. Like,

```
Deque<Integer> s = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

That changes the output to

```
4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks.

Comment: it's a nice answer that doesn't answer any of OP's questions (there are 3)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It does, between the lines. It basically says: "dont waste your time using Stacks, use Deques" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
it prints 1 2 3 4.
```

**Because Of**

Stack extends Vector  - which maintains the original insertion order , pop gives you the last object in the Stack
, In fact, I think breaking the intuitive ordering when you call stream()